# Find words from a list within a website

Tags: internet, search

**Summary:**

I need to find out if any items in my list occur in a website. I could do it manually with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, but it would take a long time.

**Description**

I have a text file with key words in this format:

```
word1
word4
word12
word24
...
```

I need to search text in a table on a website with this format:

```
RandomWord    version 1.3    ...
word1         version 1.3    ...
word2         version 2.6    ...
word5         version 1.1    ...
randomword    version 9.0    ...
word12        version 1.0    ...
...           ...            ...
```

If the above data was what I had, it would be nice to end up with this list:

```
word1
word12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this is not IE specific.

You could create a JS script like so and run it from the command line using "cscript.exe".

```
// Create object
var objXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

// Get the web page - Change to your page!
objXMLHTTP.open("GET", "http://www.google.com/index.html", false);
objXMLHTTP.send()

// Your list of words
var words = ["word1", "word4", "word12", "word24"];

// Get line
if (objXMLHTTP.Status == 200) {
    // Simple regex. You can change this if needed
    var re = new RegExp("(" + words.join("|") + ")", "i");
    // Break file into lines
    var lines = objXMLHTTP.responseText.split("\n");
    // Go through each line
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // If it's a match, print it
        if (lines[i].match(re)) {
        WScript.Echo(lines[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can't use it, in this case, but I appreciate your effort. This particular website updates specific page elements without sending me to a new URL, so I need to physically click stuff before I get to the table.